# link CustomerID with Order Date for every product SKU

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I'm trying to link some tables to create an audience for a campaign but the way I link them doesn't give me the right audience. When I check from the last week, I get many more products over £1000 then I now we sold. It looks like it doesn't link the sku(productid) to the right date.

Do you see anything wrong with the way I'm connectiont the tables? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What should the resulting audience data extension look like?

Comment: The result that I get is wrong because the SKU(productid) doesn't match the OrderDate and I can't understand why as the data in the tables is definitely right. The resulting audience should have the right orderDate appended to the SKU

Comment: When it comes to the joins, I'd start with the order header data and work your way to the SKUs -- which is not what you have illustrated in your diagram.

Answer (score 2):

You could construct your query this way to retrieve orders placed yesterday:

```sql
select
  ordhdr.customerID
, ordhdr.orderID
, ordhdr.orderDate
, orddtl.sku 
, products.productName
from Table4 ordhdr
inner join Table5 orddtl on orddtl.customerid = ordhdr.customerid
inner join Table2 products on products.sku = orddtl.sku
where ordhdr.orderDate >= convert(date, getDate()-1)
and ordhdr.orderDate < convert(date, getDate())
/* target: OrdersPlacedYesterday */
```

Then if you took the results of this and referenced a Master data extension you could get a distinct list of subscribers for your sending audience:

```sql
select
m.emailaddress
, m.customerid
from MasterDataExtension m
where exists (
 select top 1.* 
  from OrdersPlacedYesterday orders
  where orders.customerid = m.customerid
) 
/* target: OrdersPlacesYesterday_Send */
```